# How to only show Unique values in this existing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am comparing two tables (`dbo.new` and `dbo.old`) and if the first three column match and the forth column doesnst match, it has to select it. Now this shows a lot of values, and I only want to display the unique values of column2. This is the code I have now:

```
SELECT dbo.new.[column1], dbo.new.[column2], dbo.new.[column3], dbo.new.[column4]
FROM dbo.new 
JOIN dbo.old ON dbo.new.[column1]=dbo.old.[column1] 
    AND dbo.new.[column2]=dbo.old.[column2] 
    AND dbo.new.[column3]=dbo.old.[column3]
WHERE [dbo].[new].[column4] <> [dbo].[old].[column4]
```

First two tables I start with:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----------------
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
-----------------
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
-----------------

-----------------
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
-----------------
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 9 |
-----------------
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 9 |
-----------------
```

This is the outcome of the query above:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----------------
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
-----------------
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
-----------------
      ^ delete those duplicates
```

This is what I want to be the outcome:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
-----------------
```

I tried many things like `UNIQUE` and `DISTINCT` but I cant find the solution. It doenst even need to show the first value, as long as it show onea row with the unique number. So this is correct too:

```
-----------------
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
-----------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: @wouterdejong You want records with all the columns as same value? And do add some sample data, so that it will be easy to understand the issue.

Comment: you said ' if the first three column match and the forth column doesnst match, it has to select it.' to me that would mean that 1 1 1 5 would be selected.  1 1 1 1 or 1 1 5 2 are examples that would not be selected - in the first the condition that the fourth does not match is validated and in the second columns 1-3 do not match - could you clarify.

Comment: considering your final 2 examples, I cannot see exactly what is wrong with the first table you show, all of those rows in table 1 adhere to the apparent system of tables 2 & 3.

Comment: @Cato The first column is the result of the query

Comment: if the column values are changing, and you are joining using those columns, then you aren't necessarily joining table new rows to their original table old values- yeah sorry I should have read the question better though, not sure what you want to do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're only interested in column 2 so let's start with only selecting that.
Then add a simple: GROUP BY at the end and you're done.

```
SELECT N.[column2] as myvalue
FROM dbo.new N
JOIN dbo.old O
ON N.[column1]=O.[column1] 
    AND N.[column2]=O.[column2] 
    AND N.[column3]=O.[column3]
WHERE N.[column4] <> O.[column4]
GROUP BY N.[column2]
```

Comment: I get the same error here as with the code of @Serg: `Additional information: The multi-part identifier "dbo.new.column2" could not be bound.`

Comment: @wouterdejong I made an edit to the group by, try now.

Comment: @wouterdejong it may be solved with aliases, I edited the code a last time. Using aliases will also work for Serg's code.

Comment: New I get another error. `Additional information: Column 'dbo.nieuw.column1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Your code actually works, but I cannot show(select) multiple columns (column1,2,3,4)

Comment: The code will only show values from column 2, but that's because this is the way you do it if you're only interested in values from column 2. Otherwise use Serg's code.

Comment: You need to rewrite his code to use aliases. That's as far as I will go.

Answer (score 4):

Choose the ordering you need in `over()` to get proper rows.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
   dbo.new.[column1], dbo.new.[column2], dbo.new.[column3], dbo.new.[column4] 
FROM dbo.new 
JOIN dbo.old ON dbo.new.[column1]=dbo.old.[column1] 
AND dbo.new.[column2]=dbo.old.[column2] 
AND dbo.new.[column3]=dbo.old.[column3]
where [dbo].[new].[column4] <> [dbo].[old].[column4]
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by dbo.new.[column2] order by dbo.new.[column1])
```

Quick demo, runs OK sql server 2014

```
create table dbo.new(
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int,
    column4 int);
create table dbo.old(
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int,
    column4 int);
insert dbo.new values 
( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ),
( 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 ),
( 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 ),
( 4 , 1 , 4 , 4 );

insert dbo.old values 
( 1 , 1 , 1 , 9 ),
( 2 , 1 , 2 , 9 ),
( 3 , 3 , 3 , 9 ),
( 4 , 1 , 4 , 9 );


SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
   dbo.new.[column1], dbo.new.[column2], dbo.new.[column3], dbo.new.[column4] 
FROM dbo.new 
JOIN dbo.old ON dbo.new.[column1]=dbo.old.[column1] 
AND dbo.new.[column2]=dbo.old.[column2] 
AND dbo.new.[column3]=dbo.old.[column3]
where [dbo].[new].[column4] <> [dbo].[old].[column4]
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by dbo.new.[column2] order by dbo.new.[column1]);
```

Result is

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
    1     1      1       1
    3     3      3       3
```

Comment: nice one!
I didn't know "with ties"
More classic whould be a column with "row_number() over(partition by dbo.new.[column2]) number_column"
and a "where number_column = 1"

Comment: @serg Thanks, but for some reason im getting the error: ``Additional information: The multi-part identifier "dbo.new.column2" could not be bound.``

Comment: Please provide table definitions

Comment: @serg well, im the new table are more rows then the old table, is that the problem?

Comment: I see no problem with number of rows. Demo added.

Comment: @Serg I added a bit more detail in the question.

Comment: Still  can't see the problem with your data too.

Comment: looks good to me.. the top(1) with ties is a neat trick, but it adds an extra sort to your execution plan as opposed to a filter..

Comment: @Serg I dont get it, I fill in the exact same code, but it return the error @ "`over(partition by dbo.new.[column2]`". Is it maybe because im using SQL queries into Visual Studio?

Comment: Weird :( Runs OK on my side.

Comment: This `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick is an interesting spin on the old classic. Clever chap you are.

Comment: @Serg I get the exact same error with Pieter B his answer